# iOS - JSQMessage bubbles would scroll down when keyboard mode changed

Tags: ios, swift, layout, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using `JSQMessagesViewController` for my chat app.

When I change the keyboard input mode (i.e. keyboard language), the bubbles would scroll down by a height and be covered by the `inputToolbar`.

I've found this issue also appears in the `JSQMessagesViewController` Swift Example App. So this might be a bug.

I've tried to make the bubbles scroll to the bottom when the keyboard input mode changes, but it did not work. So I guess it is because the `collectionView's` bottom is below the `inputToolbar`.

Anyone could help on this issue? Thanks.

`ScreenShots`

Before change:
[Before change keyboard mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71gM8.jpg)

After change:
[After change keyboard mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvfk3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

use collectionview's method `scrollToItem`

like -

```
let itemIndex  = <Your Desired Index> or array.count - 1 (for scroll down one cell) 
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndex, section: sectionIndex)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at:indexPath,at:UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredVertically, animated: true)
```

i hope this will work ! :)